# Symfony2 OAuth2 provider error UserRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, oauth-2.0

I'm new in Symfony framework and using tutorial http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/ getting error:

`ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "UserRepository" from namespace "Acme\DemoBundle\Repository" in C:\xampp\htdocs\*****\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory.php line 75. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?`

I think that code can cause this error:

```
<!-- src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.xml -->
<parameters>
    <parameter key="platform.entity.user.class">Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User</parameter>
    <parameter key="platform.user.provider.class">Acme\DemoBundle\Provider\UserProvider</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="platform.user.manager" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"
             factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getManagerForClass">
        <argument>%platform.entity.user.class%</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="platform.user.repository"
             class="Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\UserRepository"
             factory-service="platform.user.manager" factory-method="getRepository">
        <argument>%platform.entity.user.class%</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="platform.user.provider" class="%platform.user.provider.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="platform.user.repository" />
    </service>
</services>
```

OR

```
<?php
  // src/Acme/DemoBundle/Provider/UserProvider.php

  namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Provider;

  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
  use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
  use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

  class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
  {
      protected $userRepository;

      public function __construct(ObjectRepository $userRepository){
          $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
      }

      public function loadUserByUsername($username)
      {
          $q = $this->userRepository
              ->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
              ->setParameter('username', $username)
              ->setParameter('email', $username)
              ->getQuery();

          try {
              $user = $q->getSingleResult();
          } catch (NoResultException $e) {
              $message = sprintf(
                  'Unable to find an active admin AcmeDemoBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                  $username
              );
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
          }

          return $user;
      }

      public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
      {
          $class = get_class($user);
          if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
              throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                  sprintf(
                      'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                      $class
                  )
              );
          }

          return $this->userRepository->find($user->getId());
      }

      public function supportsClass($class)
      {
          return $this->userRepository->getClassName() === $class
          || is_subclass_of($class, $this->userRepository->getClassName());
      }
  }
```

But I can not understand...

Comment: Did update your Doctrine shema with the command line? Cause I guess the entity and the repository aint created yet. So run the update command for symfony as explained here: [Symfony2/Doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema)

Comment: Did it, but error still exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is below:

Create a new folder Repository under: src/Acme/DemoBundle/

And create new file UserRepository.php with the below code.

```
<?php 
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
* UserRepository
*
* This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
* repository methods below.
*/
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

This is what will correct the error, if you notice the error it states that class UserRepository was not found in "Acme\DemoBundle\Repository". So its simple just create that class in that directory.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, here is what I did.

Create a file named **UserRepository.PHP** in **Entity** folder

Inside it, put this code

namespace Login\LoginBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

Use your proper **namespace, bundle name, class name** etc. This worked for me, hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple fix in the [Symfony2 Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Try this in the command line at the root of your project:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourAppBundle
```

It will help put the Entities in proper order and likely fix the problem. It worked for me.  : )